# How to slice a Tensor given the starting indices for each each row in TF2.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Given some (at least 2-dimensional) input, like:

```
inputs = [['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
          ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
          ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
```

...and another input of indices and a scalar window size:

```
indices = [2, 3, 0]  # representing the starting positions (2nd dimension)
window_size = 2      # fixed-width of each window
```

How can I get the windows starting at these indices in Tensorflow 2? I first though about using the regular slicing like `inputs[,start:start+window_size]`, but that is not applicable as this only allows to use one starting index for all row and does not support varying indices per row.

---

*The expected output for this sample would be:*

```
output = [['a2', 'a3'],
          ['b3', 'b4'],
          ['c0', 'c1']]
```

Comment: Perhaps remove the item at the specified index and save that to a new list?  `saveditem = inputs[0][indicies[0]]` and then `inputs[0].remove(indices[0])` then `newlist[0].append(saveditem)`?

Comment: At the moment, I'm using `tf.map_fn` to iterate over all rows and slice them individually. That works, but seems odd, as I am not even sure whether that will be executed in parallel on the GPU or whether that will cause a bottleneck when being used inside a custom layer of network.

Comment: slicing is more efficient than a for loop and is more readable, this is python, python is slow anyways compared to C++.  A good serializer should take any structure its given and prepare it for sending, as long as everything is pre processed before being sent over to the wire should be fine right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide a vectorization method. The vectorization method will be significantly faster than the `tf.map_fn()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.constant([['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
                      ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
                      ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']])
indicies = tf.constant([2, 3, 0])
window_size = 2

start_index = tf.sequence_mask(indicies,inputs.shape[-1])
# tf.Tensor(
# [[ True  True False False False]
#  [ True  True  True False False]
#  [False False False False False]], shape=(3, 5), dtype=bool)
end_index = tf.sequence_mask(indicies+window_size,inputs.shape[-1])
# tf.Tensor(
# [[ True  True  True  True False]
#  [ True  True  True  True  True]
#  [ True  True False False False]], shape=(3, 5), dtype=bool)

index = tf.not_equal(start_index,end_index)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[False False  True  True False]
#  [False False False  True  True]
#  [ True  True False False False]], shape=(3, 5), dtype=bool)

result = tf.reshape(tf.boolean_mask(inputs,index),
                    indicies.get_shape().as_list()+[window_size])
print(result)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[b'a2' b'a3']
#  [b'b3' b'b4']
#  [b'c0' b'c1']], shape=(3, 2), dtype=string)
```